# Output of a Java class run through a Python script, that is in turn executed by an Apache web server

Tags: java, python, linux, apache

I'm having a problem runnig Java class run through a Python script, that is in turn executed by an Apache web server.

I have the following file, accesible via an Apache webserver

script.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python

os.system("java HelloWorld")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The I run the script from the shell, it runs properly. However, when I access it via a web browser, the os.system("java ...") returns exit status 1536.

Any idea why this is happening?

This is running on Linux Mint 13. Please let me know what extra information I can provide.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When running the script from your command line you probably have different enviroment variables set and you have a different security content.

Make sure that your webserver finds the files (E.g. try using full path names) and check if everyone has the execute permission for java and read to the folder and file(For security reasons I'm not sure if that is a good idea tough).